# How to add a custom class to all the images for a page only?

Tags: images

I have a page where I want to add a custom class to all the images.

How to add this?

Thank you.

Comment: All images in the page content? Or all images _anywhere_ on the page, including header, footer, sidebar etc.?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your theme was created and coded properly each page has its own class already. Look at the body div in your code.  You should see something like page-id-23.  (the number is going to be different, as the number will be the actual ID of the page itself.)

So, all you have to do is use the selector  `.page-id-XX img`

This will target all images on that page.

Comment: Thank you.

Could you please suggest to me the code what will be the whole code for it?

Comment: I don't know your site or your page Id to do that.  you'd need to provide more info

Answer (score 0):

you can add custom class to images based on a page url in wp_footer hook inside child themes functions.php
below example will add custom class 'CustomImgClass' to all images inside body tag only for this (https://example.com/test/) page

```
function add_custom_class_to_images()
{
    $page_link = esc_url( get_permalink() );
    if($page_link=='https://example.com/test/')
    {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("body img").addClass('CustomImgClass');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer','add_custom_class_to_images');
```